# Fastest way to convert a matrix to a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

What is the fastest way to convert a matrix like the following to a data.table?

```
mat <- matrix(1:9, nrow = 3)

1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

I can convert this to a data.table with the code below

```
setDT(data.frame(mat))[]
```

But is this the fastest way? Can we do this without first converting it to a data.frame?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some examples to discuss about the speed of forming `data.table`, i.e., `as.data.table`, `setDT(as.data.frame(mat))` and `setDT(data.frame(mat))`.

- when rows are less than columns:

```
mat <- matrix(1:5e3, nrow = 5)
microbenchmark(unit = "relative",
               as.data.table(mat),
               setDT(as.data.frame(mat))[],
               setDT(data.frame(mat))[])

Unit: relative
                        expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
          as.data.table(mat) 1.433084 1.417747 1.340552 1.413278 1.414386 1.070289   100
 setDT(as.data.frame(mat))[] 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000   100
    setDT(data.frame(mat))[] 1.287526 1.281964 1.237544 1.284735 1.258662 1.186977   100
```

- when rows are more than columns:

```
mat <- matrix(1:5e3, nrow = 5e2)
microbenchmark(unit = "relative",
               as.data.table(mat),
               setDT(as.data.frame(mat))[],
               setDT(data.frame(mat))[])

Unit: relative
                        expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
          as.data.table(mat) 1.114003 1.041410 1.083238 1.070029 1.049262 1.254732   100
 setDT(as.data.frame(mat))[] 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000   100
    setDT(data.frame(mat))[] 1.680208 1.467538 1.482018 1.511009 1.479438 1.440440   100
```

**Remark**:
`setDT(as.data.frame(mat))[]` is the winner of speed

Comment: Wow, this is great!  It's interesting that relative number of rows and columns change the speed of the two functions.  Thank you for this detailed answer!

Comment: Why not as.data.frame rather than data.frame?

Comment: @jangorecki Thanks! I just used OP's method for comparison. I added `as.data.frame` to benchmark, so you can see the update

Comment: @johnc please check out my updated answer, it seems `setDT(as.data.frame(mat))[]` is the fastest so far

Comment: Very interesting!  Thanks, @jangorecki, for the suggestion, and Thomas, for this additional test!

Comment: Note that there is a dedicated C function coming to data.table, it should greatly reduce the time of as.matrix.data.table method. For status see https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/4144

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `magrittr` pipe:

```
mat <- matrix(1:9, nrow = 3) %>% data.table()
```

Without `magrittr`:

```
mat <- data.table(matrix(1:9, nrow = 3))
```

Comment: Thanks, Matt!  Would you happen to know how to convert it without using packages other than data.table?

Comment: I updated the answer to include `data.table()` instead of `as.data.frame()` but you'd need `magrittr` to use the `%>%`.

Comment: Haha, thank you!  I thought I had to use setDT() and didn't think of data.table(). Thank you, Matt!

Comment: No problem! feel free to click the green check mark to accept the answer if it solved your question

Comment: Sorry I had to accept the other answer because of the speed comparison.  Wish I could accept both.  But I really appreciate you taking the time to answer the question.